# How to pass state to Link from reach-router

Tags: reactjs, components, reach-router

**UPDATED CODE STILL NOT WORKING**

Haven't been able to find an answer on here to help with my problem.

In my Playlist component, I have an image that links to a new path for tracks. I want to pass a Playlist ID to the track so it can display tracks based on the ID it is given but no matter how I do this it wont work for me.

My Playlist Component returns:

```
 <Link to = '/tracks' state = {{playlist:playlist.id}}>
   <img alt = "album"src={playlist.images.url}/>
 </Link>
```

In my Track Component, it is doing the following:

```
export default class Tracks extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            playlistid: 0
        };
    }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({
                playlistid: this.props.location.state.playlistid
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>PlaylistID: {this.state.playlistid}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me which Component is wrong? Sorry I'm still quite new to React

Thanks

Comment: Is Link from some library? react-router or reach-router?

Comment: its from reach-router. Should it be from react-router?

Comment: are you using reach-router for all your routing?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am yes

Comment: Added an answer

Comment: I updated the code as I'm not sure which component is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to pass on a state to Link component from Reach router, you can pass on state as a separate prop. The `to` prop neeeds to be a string

```
<Link
     to='/tracks'
     state= {{
        playlistid: playlist.id
     }}
 >
     <img alt = "album"src={image.url}/>
 </Link>
```

For more information refer to the documentation of **[Link from Reach-router](https://reach.tech/router/api/Link)**

**EDIT:**

The way you have implemented the Link component works with react-router `Link` component

Comment: For the above code, I am getting an error for `playlistid: playlist.id` It says it expects a }

Comment: Updated the answer, there was a missing parenthesis

Comment: The issue might be how I'm handling it in the Track component so I edited my code

Comment: @Steph Do you receive any error because the way you used it is ccorrect. However you don't need to save props value to state

Comment: Oh really? There are no errors in my console to help me find any issue it just isnt displaying anything.

Comment: In such a case, could you please create a small codesandbox to actually reproduce your issue

Comment: In such a case, could you please create a small codesandbox to actually reproduce your issue

Comment: Oh I've never used this before it's a cool application! Here is the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-buck-iwvf2?file=/src/Playlist.jsx

Comment: The problem was how you set state in playlist.jsx componentDidMount. setState is a function. Working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-edison-0pjxb?file=/src/Playlist.jsx:281-431

Comment: Oh that was so stressful I can't believe how simple that mistake was. Thank you so much you've no idea how much I appreciate it I have been staring at this for 3 days now.

Comment: Haha, Happens to all of us. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<Link to={{
        pathname: `/tracks/${playlist.id}`, //I assume you tracked the tracklist state here as a props 
      }}>
   <img alt = "album"src={image.url}/>
</Link>
```

Comment: The above option doesn't have a backtick after `{playlist.id}` and when I add one it isn't recognized as a string and makes everything after this also a string.

Comment: Can you be a little more revealing? Maybe you can show it with some code ? 
I think I understand you, but I have to be sure to give the right answer.

Comment: The issue might be how I'm handling it in the Track component so I edited my code